# Calculate the sum of each column of a sparse matrix using C

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix of size (8 x 8) as shown below, I have to convert it into a form of sparse matrix and compute the sum of non-zero elements for each column using C language.

```
 Matrix =   [1 2 0 4 0 0 0 0;
             0 1 3 0 2 0 0 0;
             1 0 4 7 0 0 0 0;
             0 6 0 0 1 8 0 0;
             0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0;
             0 0 0 0 8 1 1 0;
             0 0 0 0 9 0 2 0;
             0 0 0 0 0 0 7 1]
```

Could someone please advise on how to proceed on this problem?
Please note that this is a sample matrix and in practice I have huge matrices of dimensions around (15,000 rows x 25,000 columns)

Comment: what do you mean by 'convert into sparse matrix'? this already looks like a sparse matrix

Comment: Search for "sparse matrix implementation" or something along those lines; [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representation/) was one of the top results, and seems quite useful.

Comment: what data structure are you using for the matrix right now? and what do you have in mind for the (I guess efficient) sparse representation?

Comment: The wikipedia page about [sparse matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) has some suggestions on how to store these objects. To write a conversion function you should also know/tell how the starting dense matrix is implemented.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog great! That helps, but since I'm working with a very sparse matrix where the number of zeros in a matrix are 10 times more than number of non zero elements, I'm looking for any other better alternative.

Comment: @shannon that was just to get you started. Please don't expect other users to do your research, especially when the relevant resources are so plentiful and easy to find. You should make an effort to do further research.

Comment: What type are your matrix values? Small integers? Large integers? Floating-point values? If this is the only operation to do, it'd be faster to calculate the column sums when reading the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone please advise on how to proceed on this problem?

1. Find out all required and optional operations on the sparse matrices.

   Many operations require either row-wise or column-wise data access.  Some operations (like efficient naïve matrix-matrix multiplication) require both; the particular one depending on which side of the multiplication operator the matrix is on.  Some operations benefit from simple transposing.  Collecting the operations, and sorting them by their requirements, gives you criteria you can use to pick the "best" (closest to optimal for your use cases) implementation.
2. Choose the proper type to describe the values in the matrix.

   In particular, I recommend considering float, double, unsigned char, signed char, uint*N*_t, and int*N*_t types (for *N* = 8, 16, 32, or 64).

   You need the precision and range to describe the values you have, without wasting memory for precision or range you do not need.
3. Choose which data structure(s) you will use to implement the sparse matrix.

   The Wikipedia article on [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix) describes a few typical structures (DOK, LIL, COO, CSR, CSC, Yale). If you implement more than one, you'll need to write not only all low-level operations on each, but all combinations for arithmetic operations. (For example, if your sparse matrices use either compressed sparse row (CSR) or compressed sparse column (CSC) formats, then you'll need four matrix-matrix multiplication routines depending on the types of the two argument matrices (CSR×CSR, CSC×CSR, CSR×CSC, CSC×CSC), because matrix multiplication is not commutative.)

   If performance is important, cache effects of the various data structures should be considered carefully. You'll want to examine memory in sequential order, in one or more arrays, to take advantage of CPU prefetching and caching. If there is lots of data, you'll want to "pack" everything as tight as possible (because memory bandwidth tends to be the limiting bottleneck with matrix operations), but keep the operations needed to handle each matrix element to a minimum.
4. Write basic matrix input/output routines, and unit tests to check that your data structures work correctly.

   Typically, you'll need to read and write these matrices from/to files or streams (like standard input and output). Write those first. Then, write some debug functions that describe how the matrix data is stored. At minimum, you'll want to write a test program that reads a matrix (from standard input), prints it (to standard output) and the storage format (to standard error); you can supply it with a few test case inputs (at least one with random data) to see if the roundtrip retains the correct data.  I often use awk to both generate the test data sets, and to compare numerical output to expected numerical output.
5. Write a function that given sparse matrix *M*, returns a row vector *v*, where *v<sub>i</sub>* = ∑ *M*<sub>*j*,*i*</sub>

   In other words, element *i* in *v* is the sum of all elements of *M* in column *i*.
6. Write a test program for your function, and test it.

   Typically, you'll want your program to read a matrix (from standard input), and write the vector to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone please advise on how to proceed on this problem?

You make a list that stores the non-zero elements of the matrix. For that, you need a structure that defines what an element of such a list looks like:

```
struct sparseElement{
    int n;
    int m;
    int value;
}
```

Then you translate the matrix into this sparse form by looping through it, counting the non-zero elements. Now that you know how many there are, you can allocate the memory:

```
sparseElement* sparse = malloc(n * sizeof(sparseElement))
```

Where `n` is the amount of non-zero elements. Then you can fill in the list.

> compute the sum of non-zero elements for each column using C language.

You loop through the list and sum up all elements where the column index is equal to the row that you're calculating the sum for. If you want to do it for all columns in one go you can make a list with one entry per column and then add each element to the respective index.

Of course, that's just a possible implementation. Big, established libraries use more elaborate and efficient structures/algorithms.

Comment: A good sparse matrix would still have good access speed. It implies nodes that are both horizontally and vertically linked, not a simple linked list.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm using a very sparse matrix. For every ten 1's , I've almost hundred 0's. Since I'm working with huge matrices( around 15,000 rows x 25,000 columns) as mentioned in the original question, is this method feasible? Or should I consider using any other approach? Kindly suggest a best one for a very sparse matrix.